# How to pass the application context into a broadcast receiver while keeping the constructor empty

Tags: android, constructor, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I'm currently working on a Live Wallpaper which need to keep track of the number of unread SMSs.
When an SMS is received I update the SMSCount like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX,
                                                  null,
                                                  "read = 0",
                                                  null,
                                                  null);
    mSMSCount = c.getCount();
    c.close();
}
```

which work fine. However, the value is updated only when a message is received so before that it gives an incorrect value (SMSCounts initialised value). So to initialise SMSCount to the right value I would have to initialise it with the above code. The problem being that it requires a context. When I try and pass the application context into the Broadcast receiver's constructor I get a "no empty constructor" exception.

Comment: Why pass the context on the constructor if you receive it on the onReceive method?

Comment: becausei need to initialise mSMSCount with the same code which requires a context outside of the onReceive method.

Answer (score 2):

Just go ahead and add an empty constructor to your class as well as the constructor you are currently passing a context into, So in other words, add a constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: i tried this but im getting a weird bug. it seems the onReceive is changing a seperate mSMSCount variable than the one that has already been set up. I come to this conclusion because:

at the end of my onRecieve ive added a Log.d for mSMSCount which does indeed go up everytime a txt is received. however my getSMSCount() function returns the mSMSCount value that was initialised when the SMSReceiver class started.

Comment: Accept this answer as it's solves the issue you raised, and go ahead and ask the new question with all the details and I'll try my best to help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, First things first, BroadcastReceiver is intended to receive a notification and alert someone, not to stay running, so if you have code outside onReceive your doing wrong.

From your question your doing more thing to need a Context on the constructor of your BroadcastReceiver.

My sugestion is to move all this code from onReceive to an IntentService, this service will start, do the lookup on the database and call to update the count, no instance variable because the service will end afterwards.

Then when starting your program you call this IntentService to show the unread count and also on the BroadcastReceiver you only call the IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameterised constructor as well as default constructor.